# Should you delete a question you made that is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I made [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609194/events-with-a-dynamic-xaml-ui-in-wpf) then I realized it is pretty much a duplicate to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532287/using-events-commands-with-xamlreader). Should I delete mine? Or just flag as duplicate?

Comment: This is a meta situation! Will you delete this meta question? : )